# Not able to zip file in java using zipOutputStream?

Tags: java, filewriter, zipoutputstream

Actually I was trying to zip files using zipOutputStream but everytime it is not able to zip files properly. It gets stuck at a particular file of bigger size.
My code looks like below:

```
           byte[] buf = new byte[1600*1024]; 
           long totalBytes = 0;
            if(flag){
                FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(absoluteFileName);
                zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                while ((len = fileStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("bytes read = "+len);
                    totalBytes += len;
                    System.out.println("totalBytes = "+totalBytes);
                    zip.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
```

The output looks like below:

```
  bytes read = 163840
  Total bytes = 163840
  bytes read = 163840
  Total bytes = 327680
  bytes read = 7940
  Total Bytes = 335620
```

Somehow it is not able to read beyond that. The file size is 336 KB.
So, I believe the total bytes read is file size. But when trying to open the zip file , I get some error and the file extracted is not complete. The one extracted from zip is only 2468 lines while the original file is more than 3500 lines.

Please help. I am stuck in this for last 4 days.

Comment: Did you close output file properly?

Comment: output file means zip file or the one which we are reading?

Comment: zip.close(); fileStream.close(); hope this guide can help you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: You need to close the entry (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#closeEntry--) and close the output stream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

Comment: No. It did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `Somehow it is not able to read beyond that.` ? Just afterwards you say you believe the whole file has been read; do you expect any other read? Apart from the corrupt zip and its incomplete entry, do you have any other error or weird behaviour?

Comment: Yes, when I try to extract using the command tar -xvf file.zip , it gives me error as: trucated zip file body

Comment: @Sarwan do not use tar but unzip to unzip.